# Influxdb Json (MQTT) rename field with wildcards

Tags: mqtt, influxdb, telegraf

I need help with an issue I am having sending the data of my Zigbee thermometers to influx, via telegraf.

this is the path:
Zigbee Sonoff SNZB-02 --> Tasmota ZBBridge --> MQTT --> Telegraf --> InfluxDB

The id of the zigbee thermometer: **0x4EF9** might change since it's randomly assigned to the device, in Tasmota I am able to assign a "friendly name", in this case: **ZB_Sonoff_Temp01**

With simple tasmota devices I have no issues, I have the single entry of the device in the MQTT Topic and Telegraf plays nicely with those.
My issues is with the data from the Zigbee Bridge, since it has a single topic and the output in Influx is a bit difficult to work with:

Example MQTT message for Zigbee thermometer:

```
tele/tasmota_ABDCEF/ZB_Sonoff_Temp01/SENSOR {"ZbReceived":{"0x4EF9":{"Device":"0x4EF9","Name":"ZB_Sonoff_Temp01","Humidity":94.84,"Endpoint":1,"LinkQuality":34}}}
```

the data is in Json format as you can see,
in Telegraf I am using mqtt_consumer, here is the config:
/etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/mqtt.conf

```
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  servers = ["tcp://192.168.10.10:1883"]

  ## Topics that will be subscribed to.
  topics = [
    "tele/tasmota_ABCDEF/ZB_Sonoff_Temp01/SENSOR"
  ]

  qos = 0
  connection_timeout = "30s"
  username = "user"
  password = "password"

  data_format = "json"

[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["http://localhost:8086"]
  database = "test_temp"
#  skip_database_creation = true
```

and this is my /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:

```
[global_tags]

[agent]
  logfile = "/var/log/telegraf/telegraf.log"
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = false
```

this is the data in influx:

```
time                           ZbReceived_0x4EF9_Endpoint ZbReceived_0x4EF9_Humidity ZbReceived_0x4EF9_LinkQuality ZbReceived_0x4EF9_Temperature host          topic
----                           -------------------------- -------------------------- ----------------------------- ----------------------------- ----          -----
2021-12-24T15:43:55.26962955Z  1                          99.99                      26                            32.24                         influxdb-test tele/tasmota_ABCDEF/ZB_Sonoff_Temp01/SENSOR
2021-12-24T15:43:55.560162845Z 1                                                     21                            25.18                         influxdb-test tele/tasmota_ABDCEF/ZB_Sonoff_Temp01/SENSOR
```

which could be ok, since I am able to choose the device via the "topic" field, but the problems is that the field "ZbReceived_0x4EF9_Temperature" is not "sane" in case the devices change ID when re-associating with zigbee, which might happen..

the workaround I found is to add a rename for the fields:

```
[[processors.rename]]
  [[processors.rename.replace]]
    field = "ZbReceived_0x4EF9_Temperature"
    dest = "Temperature"
  [[processors.rename.replace]]
    field = "ZbReceived_0x4EF9_Humidity"
    dest = "Humidity"
  [[processors.rename.replace]]
    field = "ZbReceived_0x4EF9_Endpoint"
    dest = "Endpoint"
  [[processors.rename.replace]]
    field = "ZbReceived_0x4EF9_LinkQuality"
    dest = "LinkQuality"
```

which changes the fields as I want (there is no Humidity but it's not always pushed, so it's ok, I am dropping the db between changes):

```
time                           Endpoint LinkQuality Temperature host          topic
----                           -------- ----------- ----------- ----          -----
2021-12-24T15:47:09.992947108Z 1        21          23          influxdb-test tele/tasmota_ABCDEF/ZB_Sonoff_Temp01/SENSOR
2021-12-24T15:47:25.868416967Z 1        13          27.06       influxdb-test tele/tasmota_ABCDEF/ZB_Sonoff_Temp01/SENSOR
```

I don't like this solution very much since it has the device ids hardcoded in telegraf config, so when I add or change a sensor I need to edit telegraf.

the problem I now have is that I would like to find a wildcard or a method to change the fields independently from the device id, like:

```
[[processors.rename]]
  [[processors.rename.replace]]
    field = "*_Temperature"
    dest = "Temperature"
```

but I am not able to find it, I've read all the docs of the methods (also strings) but I could not find a way to achieve that..

do you have any tip that could help me?

thank you very much and happy holidays!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `processors.regex.field_rename`, but I had an older version of telegraf than the latest ((1.21.1-1) over (1.20.2-1)), and so `field_rename` was not available.

The regex I've used:

```
[[processors.regex]]
  [[processors.regex.field_rename]]
    pattern = '(^ZbReceived_)\w+_'
    replacement = "${2}"
```

the result:

```
time                           Endpoint Humidity LinkQuality Temperature host          topic
----                           -------- -------- ----------- ----------- ----          -----
2021-12-24T23:51:48.289677669Z 1                 0           25.26       influxdb-test tele/tasmota_ABCDEF/ZB_Sonoff_Temp01/SENSOR
```